# Why does livewire test assertReturned fail?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, laravel-livewire

I have a simple function called `sumEquation`:

```
/**
 * Sums an equation
 *
 * @param string $equation
 * @return float|int
 */
private function sumEquation(string $equation): float|int
{
    $equationArray = preg_split('/(?=[+-])/', $equation, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    return array_sum($equationArray);
}
```

I'm trying to write a test for it right now in a Livewire test, I am trying to check if it is accurately summing two positive numbers:

```
/** @test */
public function can_sum_two_positive_numbers() {
    Livewire::test(EquationSolver::class)
        ->call('sumEquation', '2+2')
        ->assertReturned(4);
}
```

For some reason it always fails!

If I `dd(array_sum($equation_array))` inside of the `sumEquation` function, I get the correct `4`, and if I check the type of the result it's an `integer`

Does anyone know why it's failing?

Is `assertReturned()` the wrong function to use in this test?

Thanks

Comment: `var_dump(sumEquation('2+2'))`?